# How to update a value in a file by using bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a file which contains multiple lines and need to add 1 on a hex number in the "jobid" string:

```
<jobid>a3445-34729-3b34b</jobid>
```

I can use sed to filter this line, but how can I make a hex calculation?
The result value should be like this:

```
<jobid>a3445-34729-3b34c</jobid>
```

Comment: is jobid always a three section number?

Comment: what do you already try ?

Comment: Yes @TaherKhorshidi , if we make a arithmetic directly it should failed, I have filtered this line with this command: "sed -n '/<jobid>/s/[</*id>]//gp' job.xml" but no luck, I don't know how to separate the section and do the arithmetic and replace it back to the line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do hex arithmetic, prefix your number strings with '0x'.  So if you've extracted your number with sed into $n

```
> n="0x"$n
> echo $n
0x3b34b
> n=$((n+1))
> echo $n
242748              # bash saves the result as a decimal string
> printf "%x\n" $n
0x3b43c             # but you can use printf to output it in hex
```

Answer (score 0):

use this `script`:

```
#!/bin/bash
last_jobid=$(grep '<jobid>.*</jobid>' $1 | cut -d'>' -f2 | cut -d'<' -f1 | cut -d'-' -f3)
new_jobid=$((0x$last_jobid + 1))
new_jobid=$(printf "%x\n" $new_jobid)
sed -r "s|(<jobid>[^-]+-[^-]+-)[^-]+(</jobid>)|\1$new_jobid\2|" $1
```

to run it:

```
./script job.xml
```